# Best way to save a Firebase Reference in code

Tags: android, variables, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working right now in my first app using new Firebase API. And I'm having problems to keep a Firebase object reference throughout my code, because I don't know which is the right way to do this.

So, this is the case. I have a app where my users can create groups, and inside this groups (they can belong to multiple groups) they can post some stuffs. In my actual Firebase Database it looks like:

```
{
    "Posts":{
            "GroupKey1":{
               "PostKey1":{
                    "text": 
                    "imageUrl":
                    "author":{
                        ...
                    }
                }
                "PostKey2":{
                    "text":
                    "imageUrl":
                    "author":{
                        ...
                    }
                }
                "PostKey3":{
                    "text":
                    "imageUrl":
                    "author":{
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
            "GroupKey2":{
                ....
            }
        }
}
```

So, when I want to recover the posts associated to a specific group iI'm doing the next Query:

```
Query newQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts").child(mCurrentGroupID);
```

Everything is fine with that. It works, and it's fine. But I need to keep that mCurrentGroupID String keep all the lifecycle inside my group activities and fragments. Right now I'm using bundles to keep the String alive through the code but it start to be really awful.

So, my question is that, what is the best way to keep this kind of variable alive in the code? Use SharedPreferences? Still working with bundles, a static variable, a default item in a BaseActivity which is extended for the rest of activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would insist you to keep global variable to be used throughout the app in [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class which is specially meant for that in Android. [Here](http://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114&aaid=136) is a tutorial of how you can save and retrieve global variables using Application class

Answer (score 1):

Once you receive that id first time, you can store it in `SharedPreferenceManager`, in rest of the places fetch from `SharedPreferenceManager`. Keep on updating that id every time you fetch it from `Firebase`.

Comment: I already think about save it in SharedPreferences, but one user can have multiple groups, so I will need to modify this value everytime that the users change between one group to another. That's why I dont know if is the best way!

Comment: Yes every time user change group, fetch current group id from firebase and update it in prefManager.

Comment: The other way is to fetch from firebase itself, but I think it will make network call again.